# running mod_cluster mod_proxy_htt and mod_proxy_ajp together

Tags: apache

I need to use the mod_proxy_http for some requests and the mod_proxy_ajp to be used with mod_cluster. The documentation of mod_cluster specifies to either use mod_proxy_http OR the mod_proxy_ajp.
Does anybody know if it's possible to tell mod_cluster to use mod_proxy_ajp in virtual hosts while mod_proxy_http can still be used for other purposes like proxypass or mod_rewrite proxy redirects in the same Apache 2.2.xx server?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of research and testing I found out that the default protocol for mod_cluster is AJP if the mod_proxy_ajp is loaded, otherwise it reverts to HTTP protocol(mod_proxy_http). Exactly what I wanted.